# Create an array of double from 2 object properties

Tags: c#, arrays, model-view-controller

I have an object with 2 properties that I want to combine into an array. Here is my object model.
I am trying to create an array that looks like  [lattitude,Longitude] and then assign it to `LatLng`
I ended up going with this public double[] LatLng => new[] { Latitude, Longitude };

```
public class TrailerLocation
{
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public int MapZoomLevel { get; set; }
    public string BranchNumber { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public double[] LatLng { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: `public double[] LatLng { get { return new double[] { Latitude, Longitude } } }`?

Comment: Don't use a `double[]`, use an appropriate type. If you do it this way, there's nothing stopping the code giving you an empty array or an array with 100 items. Much safer to create a class or struct that holds your Lat and Long values.

Comment: I am just trying to combine those 2 values into an array so i can use that array value somewhere else. I just dont know how to create an array that has those lat and long as values.

Comment: Then update that other point so it uses something that isn't an array, using an array is a horrible code smell.

Comment: I wish I could,  the other point is a Kendo UI Map HTML Helper and requires the locationField to be an array.

Comment: @CodeCaster `public double[] LatLng => new[] { Latitude, Longitude };` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using c# 7, you might use this syntactic sugar for tuples:

```
public (double lat, double log)[] GeoLocation { set; get; }
```